# Fastest algorithm to output array containing all integers in range excluding duplicate digits

Tags: math, number, combinatorics, fastest-code

Input is a single integer in ascending digit order.

### The **only** valid inputs are:

`12`
`123`
`1234`
`12345`
`123456`
`1234567`
`12345678`
`123456789`

### The **only** valid output is an array (set; list) of `length` equal to the factorial of input:

Input - Factorial of input - Output array `length`

`12` -> `1*2` -> `2`
`123` -> `1*2*3` -> `6`
`1234` -> `1*2*3*4` -> `24`
`12345` -> `1*2*3*4*5` -> `120`
`123456` -> `1*2*3*4*5*6` -> `720`
`1234567` -> `1*2*3*4*5*6*7` -> `5040`
`12345678` -> `1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8` -> `40320`
`123456789` -> `1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9` -> `362880`

The output array is all integers of input length in lexicographical order.

For example, given input `123` -> factorial of input is `1*2*3=6` -> for each of the six array elements output the input integer and the five remaining integers of the array in lexicographic order -> `[123,132,213,231,312,321]`. Notice that the last element is always the input integer in reverse order.

### Test Cases

```
Input  Output
`12` ->  `[12,21]` // valid output, ascending numeric order
`12` ->  `[12.0,21.0]` // invalid output, output must be rounded to integer
`123` -> `[123,132,213,231,312,321]` // valid output
`123` -> `[123,132,213,222,231,312,321]` // invalid output: `222` are duplicate digits
`123` -> `[123,142,213,231,213,321]` // invalid output: `142` outside range `1-3`
`123456789` -> `[987654321,...,123456789]` // valid output, descending numeric order
`123456789` -> `[987654321,...,123456798]` // invalid output, `123456798` is greater than the minimum required integer in resulting array `123456789`
```

### Rules

- Do **not** use standard library functions for permutations or combinatorics.
- If the algorithm produces an integer greater or less than input minimum or maximum **only** the integers in the specified range must be output. (Technically, if input is `12345` we could generate all integers to `21` or `12`, though for input `12345` the only valid output **must** be within the range `12345` through `54321`).
- Output must be an array (set; list) of integers, **not** strings.
- The integers output must **not** be hardcoded.
- The output integers must **not** include duplicate digits (more than one of the same digit at that array index).

### Winning criteria

[fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code)

### Hardware, OS

Where submissions will be run

```
~$ lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 37
Model name:            Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU        P6200  @ 2.13GHz
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               2133.000
CPU max MHz:           2133.0000
CPU min MHz:           933.0000
BogoMIPS:              4256.26
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K

~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3769        1193         802         961        1772        1219
Swap:             0           0           0

~$ uname -r
4.8.0-36-lowlatency
```

Kindly explain the algorithm within the body of the answer.

For languages used other than JavaScript (which will test at Chromium 70) will take the time to install the language and test the code for the time taken to output the requirement, as there is no way (that have found) to provide uniform results as to time for every possible language used to derive output (see this [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175206/fastest-algorithm-to-output-array-containing-all-integers-in-range-excluding-dup#comment422234_175206)).

Comment: Fastest-algorithm doesn't work for this. With an upper limit on the input, all solutions are automatically O(1).

Comment: @Dennis How so, when there must be comparisons and exclusions? Have simply been adding `9` to the input at code here, which requires a variable amount of comparisons or exclusions for each increment of `9`; is that O(1) https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/? _"O(1) describes an algorithm that will always execute in the same time (or space) regardless of the size of the input data set."_. Unless you are seeing the question differently than here? What tag is appropriate?

Comment: The asymptotic complexity isn't an exact formula, but an upper bound. Any finite set is always bounded by a constant. Unless you want to turn your contest into a fastest-code challenge (which would require running all the submissions on the same computer, to decide which one is the fastest), I don't see an easy fix.

Comment: @Dennis Will run all submissions on this old machine, yes.

Comment: Fastest-code works then. Make sure to include your machine's specs (hardware and OS) in the challenge, so people can tune for it.

Comment: @Dennis Will the output of `free -m` and `lspcu` suffice?

Comment: @Dennis Updated. Kindly state if any content at the question needs clarification.

Comment: Sure, that's more than enough.

Comment: How about giving this a less clumsy title like "find all permutations of the input" with "- distinct values guaranteed"

Comment: @Dennis Is https://tio.run/# the optimal resource for uniformly checking the time code takes to complete? If yes, which of "Real time", "User time" or "Sys. time" is the appropriate measurement of the time the code takes to complete?

Comment: [Is TIO acceptable for fastest-code questions?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12708/12012)

Comment: @Dennis Noticed some seeming irregularities when testing the code at the answer and JavaScript code before posting an answer (though am relatively certain the algorithm that am using coded in JavaScript is not the fastest code). Was not sure if when output is "truncated" the timers still run. What do you suggest using or implementing for a common testing solution for this question, or any fastest-code question; use tio anyway?

Comment: You shouldn't use *any* shared computer for timing code; TIO is no exception. Your best bet is to run the code on your own machine.

Comment: And the program is terminated, once the output limit is reached.

Comment: @Dennis Installed Haskell and Node.js. Will try to first run the Haskell code at answer, then own approach at Node.js. That leaves timing the execution. Will probably be asking you more questions, in order to be in accord with https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/175206/fastest-algorithm-to-output-array-containing-all-integers-in-range-excluding-dup?noredirect=1#comment422143_175206. If you are not interested in answering the questions relevant to to the above, simply say so; and will, in time, find solutions to list all relevant times of code at answers at the question.

Comment: So far have been able to compile and run Haskel code following https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_in_5_steps though not sure how to measure the time from beginning of execution to output limit reached. Having various issues compiling JavaScript es2016 code to run in nodejs.

Comment: @xnor What part of the question is not clear to you?

Comment: While it may be _"hard to tell exactly what you're asking"_ according to the reason cited for close votes for several users, it is **impossible** to _"clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need"_ where those users who have voted to close the question citing "unclear what you're asking" have made absolutely no attempt to clarify what is not clear _to them_ at the question.

Comment: I think Titus might be on to something in regards to the clarity of your question. If you're asking for digit permutations then you can simply say that. I didn't vote to close but I can agree that the current writeup is a bit clunky if that's all you're asking for.

Comment: I think this challenge is not interesting. **1**. Output all permutations is a very classical task to do, there are numerous existing fast algorithms. **2**. Banning library functions is not going to help anything -- people can copy the code from library. **3**. Because there exists algorithms that runs in the time equal to the output size, output printing time is going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: @user202729 When have attempted to post a challenging question here users do not understand the question and vote to close https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173145/ The same response occurred when asked the question at "MathOverflow" https://mathoverflow.net/q/314955/131181 where supposedly "MathOverflow's primary goal is for users to ask and answer research level math questions, the sorts of questions you come across when you're writing or reading articles or graduate level books." https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/44/138305 If you understand that question it will keep you busy

Comment: @user202729 Should we try again to ask the above referenced question here at PPCG?

Comment: @user202729 https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/175677/31257

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 6.9 s

```hs
f [] [x] = [[x]]
f [] [x,y] = [[x,y],[y,x]]
f l (x:r) = map (x:) (f [] $ l++r) ++ f (l++[x]) r
f _ [] = []

g :: Int -> [Int]
g = map read . f [] . show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxLCsIwAET3OcUsumhILfjXgu49QwgSsD9Ma0kF29PH6Wc1wzzmVbZ/586FUEAb6MHgBs0wYh2ScZ1YEj0mC3KIh8xLksZ2U5eI50MEpxSBUigQs9Ml4Xl5TpgmI0SJLMOj/WJzh2YaLovJ5/aFFLMqRV99fqGxdUva@ZqHCCW2u/3heDpfruEP) `g` is the main function which converts the input to a string and the result to a list of integers. `f` recursively performs the shuffling.

The algorithm works as follows: Given `123`, we need to generate `[123,132,213,231,312,321]`. This can be done in parts by taking the first digit `1`, recursively computing the list for the remaining digits `23 -> [23,32]` and adding `1` to the front again: `[123,132]`. Then we do the same with `2` and the remaining digits `13` to get `[213,231]` and with `3` and `12` to get `[312,321]`. Finally, the three lists are concatenated.

This works in the same way for larger numbers. `f` handles two lists, the first one (`l`) contains all digits left from the current digit, the second one (`x:r`) has the current digit `x` at the first position, followed by the remaining digits `r`. We recursively call `f` with all but the current digit (that is `l` and `r` concatenated) `(f [] $ l++r)` and add the current digit `x` to the front of each element in the resulting list: `map (x:)`. We then finished processing `x` and add it to the end of the `l` list and recursively call `f (l++[x]) r` to handle the next digit.

---

The largest test case `g 123456789` takes ~6.9s on OPs machine:

```hs
real 0m6.877s user 0m4.439s sys 0m0.056s
```

(~0.1s on my own machine)

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm. Is the time referenced at the answer the result at linked tio, or was another method used to measure time to complete the task?

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm? `$ time runhaskell f.hs >> output real 0m30.826s
user 0m17.053s
sys 0m13.613s`

Comment: Is `runghc` installed when `haskell-platform` is installed? `$ dpkg --get-selections | grep runghc` does not output any result

Comment: @guest271314 I added an explanation. I do not recall installing `runghc` independently, so it should be part of the Haskell platform.

Comment: @guest271314 Also the timing is actually faster if you compile first and then run the program, e.g. `ghc --make -O2 code.hs`. Then the last testcase runs in ~ 1.3 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Ran `$ ghc --make -O2 code.hs` then `$ time runhaskell code.hs >> output`: `real 0m31.279s
user 0m16.806s
sys 0m14.195s` at an old machine. Is there another step within the process of compiling the program first? Or, just the fact the machine is old and RAM differences?

Comment: @guest271314 After compiling with ghc, you don't need `runhaskell` anymore, just run the `code` executable.

Comment: Running the executable `real 0m6.877s
user 0m4.439s
sys 0m0.056s`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript 0.185 Seconds

```
function fact(x) {

  x+=""
  var rL=1,rI=0,i=0
  if(x.length <2)return [x]
  for(i;i<x.length;i++)rL*=(i+1);
  var r = new Array(rL);
  function loop(p, s) {
    var l = s.length, i=0;
    if (l === 2) {
      r[rI++] = (p + s)*1;
      r[rI++] = (p + s.charAt(1) + s.charAt(0)) * 1;
      return;
    }
    while (i < l) {
      loop(p + s.charAt(i), s.substr(0,i) + s.substr(++i));
    }
  }
  loop("",x)
  return r;
}
```

This function creates an array r of length "factorial of input length".  It then has a recursive loop of with parameters for prefix and suffix (p and s).  It starts the loop with an empty prefix and a suffix of the input.  It then checks the base case of suffix length equal to 2 and if reached adds those results.  If it's not a base case then loop through the suffix characters, take a character at index and add it to prefix, remove that character from the suffix, and loops those as a new prefix and suffix.  This will continue until input length factorial results are added to array r.

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm?

Comment: First call at `console` using `.time()` and `.timeEnd()` was `133.01708984375ms` or `0.133017089843749992` seconds; second call `223.14404296875ms`, third call `199.989013671875ms`.

Comment: Hi @guest271314. I added an explanation. Hope it helps!.

Answer (score 1):

**Common Lisp SBCL  0.157 seconds**

```
(defun num-permutations (list)
  (cond ((null list) nil)
        ((null (cdr list)) (list list))
        (t (loop for element in list
             append (mapcar (lambda (l) (cons element l))
                            (num-permutations (remove element list)))))))
```

here is the run with 1-9

```
CL-USER> (time (num-permutations '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)))
Evaluation took:
  0.157 seconds of real time
  0.156455 seconds of total run time (0.140332 user, 0.016123 system)
  [ Run times consist of 0.081 seconds GC time, and 0.076 seconds non-GC time. ]
  99.36% CPU
  468,738,490 processor cycles
  165,083,680 bytes consed
```

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm?

Comment: How to get the `CL-USER>` prompt? Installed `sbcl` and ran the program which printed to `STDOUT` though `time` was not printed.

Answer (score 1):

### C# (31 ms)

```csharp
    static int[] Foo(int perm) {
        int n = perm.ToString().Length, fact = n;
        int[] pow10 = new int[n];
        pow10[n - 1] = 1;
        for (int k = n - 2; k >= 0; k--) {
            pow10[k] = 10 * pow10[k + 1];
            fact *= k + 1;
        }

        int[] rv = new int[fact];
        rv[0] = perm;
        int z = 1, i = n - 1, pi = perm/pow10[i]%10;
        while (true) {
            int pidec = perm/pow10[i-1]%10;
            if (pidec > pi) {
                if (--i == 0) return rv;
                pi = pidec;
            }
            else {
                int j = n - 1;
                while (perm/pow10[j]%10 < pidec) j--;

                perm += (perm/pow10[i-1]%10 - perm/pow10[j]%10) * (pow10[j] - pow10[i-1]);
                for (j = n - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
                    perm += (perm/pow10[i]%10 - perm/pow10[j]%10) * (pow10[j] - pow10[i]);

                rv[z++] = perm;
                i = n - 1;
                pi = perm/pow10[i]%10;
            }
        }
    }
```

[Online demo](https://tio.run/##lZNNb9swDIbP9q/gZYBdx57dfcNNL/s4tcCADNgh8EFwFEepIxmSEmMd8ttTUpLbtFgPyyE2yfclH1Fwa/JWaX467Y2QHSz@GMt3dXweFd8E66QyVrSmjuO2Z8bAT606zXbwN46MZViCgxIruGVCJsZqdC8bYLozKUmiA9NgRpiD5CMsrBpGZttNktZYM2OxsExbH5FSH1D5Q6mkunz3/sPHT5@/PAnV4HVflTSq58VvLSy/EZInWP7es8HwVfFLWdbfir4XhrdKrgxZjvEjq5AW8WgCvsHA9c5jUiRxNmWwycIdJEmLGy47u5nBmrWWDlF7LfYY1FiV4VyUkQ3VXHYpIYeqwWJFubXS4MbdkRxLlzW@Xs@hxGeee4DgvHOuEi4gxJBhJ@oSOYSLObgUZehYAcbtbSIhobPow7JswqECONxT/xmIgIKvgwiSt36kaN5UJcnHjeg5JFbveWB0OxMr3r5w5NXkicQaEi@5RmnwuWye4yA8dAqa272WCO0ckQcgj4uP9Md7wycvDt1OuN4RyM4QtgQAV75NCts8r2PfHDWQzZ@JAy/2e9khxcUnU0z1R33qJ7u7fKLBPV7BFh9ZNqOhKYrgld8/Sf6PgygcBt7sfZad3y3u6fmOXr1Wt@AjfRXH0@kB)

The algorithm is the [standard one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order).

Comment: Is the output intended to be `30.9692` instead of _"The only valid output is an array (set; list) of length equal to the factorial of input"_ at linked tio?

Comment: Have not run *indows in quite some time. How to install .NET version of C# at *nix to test?

Comment: That's the output of the timing framework. The array is the return value of the method `Foo`. For Linux your choices are Mono and .Net Core. Don't know what options there are for BSD.

Comment: The expected output is the array of integers. Will attempt to install Mono and test the code. Compilation instructions?

Comment: `mono-csc Foo.cs` will produce `Foo.exe` which I think can run as `./Foo.exe` and if not can run as `mono Foo.exe`

Comment: FYI [Mono documentation](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) states use `csc` _"To compile, use csc: `csc hello.cs`"_ which `apt` suggests to install [`chicken-bin`](http://www.call-cc.org/): does not appear related to Mono compilation. Not sure if you want to notify the authors of the documentation that their publication for testing Mono at Debian is not accurate. Testing: `$ mono-csc p.cs
p.cs(1,11): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol \`int', expecting \`class', \`delegate', \`enum', \`interface', \`partial', or \`struct'
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings`

Comment: Using the full code at tio `$ mono-csc p.cs
p.cs(8,7): warning CS0219: The variable \`rv' is assigned but its value is never used
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
`. Test results `$ mono p.exe
47.8145
`

Answer (score 0):

## C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>

#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

unsigned char bsr(unsigned long* index, unsigned long long mask)
{
    if (!mask) return 0;
    *index = 63 - __builtin_clzll(mask);
    return 1;
}

std::vector<uint32_t> findPermulations(uint32_t input)
{
    std::string tmp = std::to_string(input);
    size_t size = std::distance(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    uint8_t* perm = (uint8_t*)_mm_malloc(32, 64);
    memcpy(perm, tmp.data(), size);
    memset(perm + size, 0, 64 - size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        perm[i] -= '0'; // Convert char to uint8_t
    }


    size_t fact = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        fact *= perm[i];
    }

    std::vector<uint32_t> results;
    results.reserve(fact);
    results.push_back(input);

    for (size_t i = 1; i < fact; i++)
    {
        uint8_t k;
        __m128i mask = _mm_cmplt_epi8(_mm_load_si128((__m128i*)perm), _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(perm + 1)));
        unsigned long index = 0;
        if (!bsr(&index, _mm_extract_epi64(mask, 1))) {
            if (!bsr(&index, _mm_extract_epi64(mask, 0))) k = size - 1;
            else k = index / 8;
        }
        else k = (index / 8) + 8;

        uint8_t l = 8;
        mask = _mm_cmplt_epi8(_mm_set1_epi8(perm[k]), _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)perm));
        if (!bsr(&index, _mm_extract_epi64(mask, 1))) {
            bsr(&index, _mm_extract_epi64(mask, 0));
            l = 0;
        }

        l += index / 8;

        std::swap(perm[k], perm[l]);
        std::reverse(perm + k + 1, perm + size);

        uint32_t result = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            result *= 10;
            result += perm[i];
        }

        results.push_back(result);
    }
    _mm_free(perm);
    return results;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Press any key to begin...\n";
    std::cin.get();
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto perms = findPermulations(123456789);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Completed in " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end - start).count() << "ms\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Regular algorithm. If `std::reverse` count counts as a library permutation function, replace with:

```
void reverse(uint8_t* first, uint8_t* last){
    while ((first != last) && (first != --last)) {
        std::iter_swap(first++, last);
    }
}
```

Swaps don't really count as permutations, put you could change them anyway.

Compile with clang 6.0:
`clang++-6.0 find.cpp -O3 -mssse3`
`./a.out`